# How to readFile() with async / execFile() Node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, electron

Thanks in advance.

I'm creating an `Electron-Create-React-App` using `electron-forge` on `Windows 10 Pro` and am stuck with using `async` functions with `execFile` and `readFile()`.

I want  to achieve the following:-

1. `main process` - Receive a buffer of a screen capture (video) from the `renderer` process.
2. Create a temporary file and write the buffer to a .mp4 file.
3. Crop the video (based on `x:y:width:height`) using `ffmpeg` (installed in `Electron` as a binary).

`Output` = .mp4 file in temporary directory

4. Read the cropped .mp4 file using `fs.readFile()` (as a `base64` encoded buffer)
5. Send the buffer to another renderer screen.
6. Delete temp file.

Q: I've managed to do most of it but cannot access the cropped .mp4 file in the temp directory.

I've tried the following:-

`Electron` `main process`

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')



ipcMain.on("capture:buffer", async (video_object) => {

  const {x_pos, y_pos, window_width, window_height, buffer} = video_object

  try {

  const dir = await fs.mkdtemp(await fs.realpath(os.tmpdir()) + path.sep)

  const captured_video_file_path = path.join(dir, "screen_capture_video.mp4")


 // This works
  await fs.writeFile(captured_video_file_path, buffer, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
            }
            console.log("Screen Capture File written")
          })


// This also works

  execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, 

        
        ['-i', `${captured_video_file_path}`, '-vf', 
        `crop=${window_width}:${window_height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}`, 
          `${path.join(dir,'cropped_video.mp4')}`],
        
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error.message)
            }
            if (stderr) {
              console.log(stderr)
            }
           console.log("Cropped File created")
          })

// This code onwards doesn't work

  await fs.readFile(path.join(dir, "cropped_video.mp4"), 'base64', (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }

// To renderer
      mainWindow.webContents.send("main:video_buffer", Buffer.from(data))
    })




} catch (error) {

  console.log(error)
} finally {
  fs.rmdir(dir, {recursive: true})

}

})
```

When trying to read the file i get the following error :-

`[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\temp\temp_eYGMCR\cropped_video.mp4']`

I've checked that the correct path exists with `console.log`.

I suspect it is a 'simple' issue with using `async` / `execFile()` properly but don't know exactly where I am making a silly mistake.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `fs.promises.writeFile()` which you are using does NOT accept a callback as it's last argument. Errors are communicated back via a rejected promise.  So, if you want to `await` that promise (like you are doing), then errors are caught with a `try/catch` around it.

Comment: Also, without converting your `execFile()` to a promise, you MUST continue your processing in the completion callback.  Or, use `util.promisify()` with `child_process.execFile()` to get a promisified version of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Because at that time of calling `fs.readFile`, execFile may not be done yet.

Untested, but you may want to create a promise and wait for execFile to be completed before proceeding and see whether it works.

```
  await new Promise( resolve => {
     execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, 

        
        ['-i', `${captured_video_file_path}`, '-vf', 
        `crop=${window_width}:${window_height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}`, 
          `${path.join(dir,'cropped_video.mp4')}`],
        
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error.message)
            }
            if (stderr) {
              console.log(stderr)
            }

           console.log("Cropped File created")
           resolve() //this tells `await` it's ready to move on
          }) 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers guys.

Here's the solution I  found.

Another big problem with safely creating and removing temporary directories in Electron is `fs.rmdir()` doesn't work when using Electron-Forge / Builder due to an issue with ASAR files.

(ASAR files are used to package Electron apps).

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises



 ipcMain.on("capture:buffer", async (video_object) => {

  const {x_pos, y_pos, window_width, window_height, buffer} = video_object

  const temp_dir = await fsPromises.mkdtemp(await fsPromises.realpath(os.tmpdir()) + path.sep)

  const captured_video_file_path = path.join(dir, "screen_capture_video.mp4")

try {
    await fsPromises.writeFile(captured_video_file_path, buffer)
}
 catch (error) {console.error}


// note no callback req'd  as per jfriends advice



let child_object = 

  execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, 

        
        ['-i', `${captured_video_file_path}`, '-vf', 
        `crop=${window_width}:${window_height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}`, 
          `${path.join(dir,'cropped_video.mp4')}`],
        
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error.message)
            }
            if (stderr) {
              console.log(stderr)
            }
           console.log("Cropped File created")
          })


child_object.on("close", async 
() => {


try {  video_buffer = await fsPromises.readFile(path.join(dir, "cropped_video.mp4")


// To renderer
  
  
 mainWindow.webContents.send("main:video_buffer",  video_buffer)


} catch (error) {
        log(error)
      } finally {
        process.noAsar = true 
        fs.rmdir(temp_directory, {recursive: true}, (error) => {if (error) {log(error)}})
        console.log("Done !!!")
        process.noASAR = false
        }
                
      })
```